# Master page gives error

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am using VS2008 for ASP.NET apps.

My Solution Explorer has hierarchy like this:

[image]

The start-up page, Default.aspx, displays a Login form. When I press Login button, another Page with the name, selectCompany, should open. selectCompany is a Web Content Form whose master page is Master1.Master. But it is not opening, instead I am getting this error:

```
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

    Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'FlexStock.Forms.master1'.

    Source Error:

    Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="~/Forms/selectCompany.aspx" Inherits="FlexStock.Forms.master1" %>
    Line 2:  
    Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


    Source File: /Forms/master1.Master    Line: 1
```

The first line of Master1.master is like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="master1.master.cs" Inherits="FlexStock.Forms.master1" %>
```

And the first line of Web Content Form, selectCompany.aspx, is like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Forms/master1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="selectCompany.aspx.cs" Inherits="FlexStock.Forms.selectCompany" %>
```

I am not following where is the problem.

Comment: Is it really a Web Application project? Because I don't see your bin folder.

Comment: @Louis Yes it is a Web App. I can see the bin folder through Windows Explorer but not through VS. The above image is of VS Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the **class-name** stated in the *Inhertis*-part of your page-directive **matches** the name of the class in your **code-behind file**.

Master1.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="master1.master.cs" Inherits="FlexStock.Forms.master1" %>
```

Master1.Master.cs:

```
namespace FlexStock.Forms {
    public class master1 {
        /* ... */
```

Comment: I moved master1.Master to the root folder and updated the line: Inherits="FlexStock.master1", now it gives error: 'FlexStock.master1' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage'.

Comment: I also changed master1.Master.cs as: namespace FlexStock.

Comment: I'd say your error indicates there are other classes named the same thing and they are colliding. Otherwise make sure your FlexStock.master1 actually inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you built your project w/o any errors/warning?

Error says that its unable to find code-behind class `FlexStock.Forms.master1` so issue will be likely in `master1.Master.cs` or `designer.cs` - where you may have changed the namespace or class name w/o making the same change in markup. Or there is some compilation error and VS is unable to generate the assembly (or unable to put it in bin folder)

Comment: It builds without errors. Now it is giving error: FlexStock.master1' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage'.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the bin folder in Explorer, but not in VS, try "Including" it in your project.

Maybe drag the folder into Solution Explorer, and then right-click it and Include it.