# An error has occurred in the script. Line 1 Error Expected ')' - ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I get this script error from the windows form.

[image]

From our .Net Page, If I removed this code:

[image]

It's working fine. Please help me to fix this without removing the code from the screenshot above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Code should be like This `AutoEventWireup="true"`. Also Make sure that the class-name stated in the Inhertis-part of your page-directive matches the name of the class in your code-behind file.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828968/master-page-gives-error)

Comment: Thanks, but after compiled from the IDE it's lowercase now. I will try that.

Comment: i think this is unrelated to your problem , you have Javascript issues in your application.